# Flutter - How to link social account using Firebase facebook and google plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I have a `flutter` app and would like the user to authenticate both with `FB` and `Google`. I do not want multiple accounts, just a single account that links both.

I am using :

```
firebase_auth 0.15.1

google_sign_in 4.0.14

facebook_plugin 3.0.0
```

I am not able to get the email address of the user when the user's account already exist with a different `provider`. The email is needed in order to get the list of providers for that user using the API call `"fetchSignInMethodsForEmail"`

Here is an example:

1: `User login` with Google credentials. The account is created in `firebase` and google is linked.

2: The user now `logoff`

3: The user now tries to login with `FB` with the same email.

-- User get the following error

```
code:"ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL"
details: null
message: "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address., **null**))
```

As you can see the `email` is `null`. I need the email in order to get a list of `providers`. Then I can `redirect` the user to correct provider

here is a snippet of my code

```
Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithFacebook({bool isIos}) async {
 AuthCredential credential;
 try {
  final FacebookLoginResult result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
  if (result.accessToken != null) {
     credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
            accessToken: result.accessToken.token
     );
     AuthResult authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
          credential,
     );
     firebaseUser = authResult.user;
        return firebaseUser;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Thanks for your help